# How can I get inside the castle safely?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've been battling the castle guards for ages and I have been getting no where! just losing a bunch of candies from all the health potion making. What is the quickest way to beat all the guards?

Answer (score 1):

Your best tactic is to use the Sponge to shrink yourself down. You're then small enough to fit under the horses and can get past with ease (still take a health potion or two with you).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing this. If you want to avoid combat, you can do so with either the sponge from the sea (allowing you to go under the horses) or the rocket boots from the desert fortress.

If you want to fight your way through, you need to have a large amount of health from eating candies and be well equipped. If you haven't done so already, get your equipment enchanted. It's a difficult fight but it's beatable with one of the following lists:

Summoning- summon and hide behind things:

- Enchanted tribal spear
- Obsidian Octopus Crown
- Pink Leather Gloves
- Pogo stick (to get past all the summons)

Blasting- do as much damage as you can before the knights reach you and keep moving forward:

- Enchanted Monkey Wizard Staff
- Jasper Octopus Crown
- Red Leather Gloves
- Healing potions

Which ever method you go for, you should have plenty of health, the lightweight body armor and the heart plug- more health means not dying.

Comment: Hm, I thought the desert fortress was only accessible *after* you had been in the castle.

Comment: @JohntheGreen The key can be found in The Hole.